# CASE OR IF IN SQL STATEMENT

Tags: sql

Tables with course_article, gr_article and user_score.

> The course can have many articles within a course: 7 can have articles 1,2,5,6,7.
>
> Only few articles are graded among: 1,6 and 2,5,7 are not graded.
>
> User attempts all the articles: can get only graded articles 1,6 from gr_article and 2,5,7 from course_article.

I want all the courses, with articles and user score in one table as shown in the output.

```
SELECT u.userid ,
       c.cid ,
       a.id ,
       u.score ,
       ( CASE WHEN c.cid = a.cid THEN u.score
              ELSE 0
         END ) AS "score"
FROM   course_article c
       JOIN gr_article a ON c.cid = a.cid
       JOIN user_score u ON u.a_id = a.id
WHERE  u.userid = 8
       AND c.cid = 7;
```

When I execute the query, it shows only the graded articles that user attempted, but I need all the course articles to be shown.

Tables

```
course_article
+--------------+
|   id  cid    |
+--------------+
|     1    7   |
|     2    7   |
|     3    5   |
|     4    5   |
|     5    7   |
|     6    7   |
|     7    7   |
+--------------+

gr_article
+------------------------+
| id  cid  article_name  |
+------------------------+
| 1    7       A1        |
| 2    7       A4        |
| 3    7       A5        |
| 4    7       A3        |
| 5    7       A2        |
| 6    7       A44       |
| 7    7       A6        |
+------------------------+

user_score
+------------------------------+
|   id  a_id  userid   score   |
+------------------------------+
|     1    2      8       3.4  |
|     2    3      3       2.0  |
|     3    4      8       6.7  |
|     4    5      3       4.5  |
|     5    1      8       5.6  |
+------------------------------+
```

Output

```
+-----------------------------+
|  userid cid  a_id   score   |
+-----------------------------+
|       8     7    2      3.4 |
|       8     7    4      6.7 |
|       8     7    1      5.6 |
|       8     7    5       0  |
|       8     7    6       0  |
|       8     7    7       0  |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Garima Gupta It was tables, not database

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: juergen Thank You for the link, but still need support from the above JOINS

Comment: @DexterSteven Your table structure is very confusing. Can you explain the common columns between these 3 tables? There seems to be some missing column.

Comment: Ankur Patel course_article and gr_article matchs with a column cid AND gr_article and user_score matches with common columns gr_article (id) = user_score(a_id). Th're  no matching records or no connection between user_score and course_article.

Comment: @DexterSteven Can you please explain what is the a_id in your output table. Because if it is the a_id from user_score then where does the 5,6 & 7 come from?

Comment: user_score is at user level report and course_article,gr_article are at course level report. What I want the report to be at course level with user scores as a add-on column.

Comment: Output: a_id is gr_article(id).

Comment: Ankur Patel, edited the table gr_article. Could you have a look.

Comment: @DexterSteven Are you sure your output is correct? Take a look at the second row of your output. You are getting cid = 7, but how? The scrore of 6.7 is in a_id = 4. so the corresponding cid in gr_article is 5 not 7.

Comment: @Ankur Patel. You're right, lets concentrate only on course (cid): 7. I tried LEFT JOIN, but still it shows the wrong score for userid.

Comment: @Ankur Patel. Is there a way to take out user score

Answer (score 1):

You need to first identify which courses a user should be graded, and then perform an `OUTER JOIN` so you can show the `0.0` for articles not yet graded.

Assuming there is no table relating `user` to `course`, perhaps you can infer this relationship by assuming that a user is related to course if the user has received at least 1 grade for an article in the course.

Then, you get a query similar to this below:

```
SELECT
    uc.userid,
    a.cid,
    a.id AS a_id,
    COALESCE(us.score, 0) AS score -- If no user score, assume 0
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        us.userid,
        a.cid
    FROM user_score us
        INNER JOIN gr_article a
            ON us.a_id = a.id
    ) uc -- Get user/course relationship
    INNER JOIN gr_article a
        ON uc.cid = a.cid -- Get all possible articles for user courses
    INNER JOIN course_article ca
        ON uc.cid = ca.cid -- Join back to course article as requested (not sure exactly of conditions you may need)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_score us -- Get available scores by article for user
        ON us.userid = uc.userid
            AND us.a_id = a.id
 WHERE uc.userid = 8 -- Here is sample filter by user id
```

**Updated to show how to filter by user id**

If you are going to filter by user id, then it needs to be `uc.userid` and not `us.userid` - otherwise it makes the `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. I updated the query to show user id filter example.

Here is a SQL Fiddle for the query with the userid filter:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1b8d/12/0

Comment: Jason: You're not using course_article table at all, then only graded courses will come out, what about non-graded courses.

Comment: I got the same output executing your query as in my query from the question

Comment: If you filter by userid, it needs to be `uc.userid` and not `us.userid`. Otherwise, you effectively make the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Here is a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1b8d/12/0

Comment: The query was good to go, could you use course_article table also, as because I have few more conditions to the query.

Comment: I added an `INNER JOIN` to course_article, but not sure of exact conditions you may have to join for it - I don't understand the difference really in course_article and gr_article. Hopefully that will work for you :)